# ColdFusion ORM: Can I specify init arguments to be passed to related entities when loaded?

Tags: orm, coldfusion

Say I have a **Page** entity which can have an array of associated **Document** entities: a straightforward one-to-many relationship.

```
<cfcomponent entityName="Page" persistent="true" table="pages">

  <!--- A Page can have many Documents --->
  <cfproperty name="document" fieldType="one-to-many" cfc="Document" fkColumn="pageID" inverse="true">

</cfcomponent>
```

However, each Document needs to know the path of its file system directory and the value of this property can vary according to context, therefore it is not persistent and needs to be passed in on instantiation.

```
<cfcomponent entityName="Document" persistent="true" table="documents">

  <!--- This value needs to be set so the document knows its location --->
  <cfproperty name="directoryPath" persistent="false">

  <!--- Many Documents can belong to one Page --->
  <cfproperty name="page" fieldType="many-to-one" cfc="Page" fkColumn="pageID">

  <cffunction name="init" output="false">
    <cfreturn this/>
  </cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

If I were loading the array of documents for the page manually or using a Bean Factory, I could specify the **directoryPath** variable as an argument passed to the Document init() method. But here, the loading of the documents is done automatically by Hibernate.

Is there a way of passing init arguments to related objects when they are loaded by the ORM?

I know I can loop over the documents once loaded and specify the directory, and perhaps that's best practice, but passing the value to each on init seems more efficient. Is it possible?

Comment: why isn't the file system path a property of `Document`?  Seems to me that would be a simple solution.

Comment: @JonathanWilson. Sorry, I obviously wasn't clear enough. The path *is* a property of Document. My question is about setting its value. Can the ORM be told to pass in the value on init() when the child array is loaded? Seems like the answer is no - has to be set by manually looping over the array once loaded.

Comment: Have added the Document definition to make things clearer.

Comment: I'm still not clear on your use case.  Are you setting and persisting the document(s) for the first time, or are you wishing to set this property every time you load a document from the database? If the latter, why?

Comment: Apologies again Jonathan, I failed to explain that the directoryPath property is *not* persistent, since it varies according to the context. Hence it needs to be set each time a Document is instantiated. I want to know if the ORM can do this for me when it loads the array. I assume the answer is no, but if there were a way it would be more efficient. Question updated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking through documentation it doesn't seem that there is a way to do what you ask.

One thing I would suggest is instead of looping through documents to set the property, you could set a property in Page object and access it from Document.

So after loading Page you would have something like `Page.setDocumentPath(documentPath);`.

then when displaying documents you could have something like `document.getPage().getDocumentPath();`.

Comment: That's a great idea which would work for the example I posted (hence marking as the answer). In reality though my "Document" objects are less tightly coupled: they can belong to many different types of object (not just Pages), or none (standalone Documents) so I don't make them aware of the parent at all. In which case I think I'm stuck with looping. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: I was trying to find a way to inject something into ORM created entity. Not sure yet how to do this but there is reference here, if you can decipher what they are talking about, let me know :-) . https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/cf-orm-dev/beaninjector/cf-orm-dev/1k2Z0w2RBPQ/ewFHqBYdWkcJ So you could have a some object that knows about your context and inject it onto Document possibly with postLoad() event handler.